# Database design: menus table for a cms

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database-design

I want to design the `menus` table for a cms. I already have `categories`, and `contents` table. a menu is a link to a specific category or a content or it can be a url from other websites.

How can I define each menu is a category or a content?
I taught it's good to have `category_id`, `content_id`, and `url` columns, all nullable.

Is this a good approach? What's the best way?

Should I add a column named `menu_type` to define type of menu, which can have this values: url, category or content. Is it necesserly to create another table like this:

**id | type_name**

1  | category

2  | content

3  | url

and in menu_type column insert 1 for category 2 for content... as foreign keys?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you don't have any extra attributes that are specifically related to the type, you could use an `enum()` column. With it, the strings "category", "content", and "url" are only stored once and an ID is stored on each record. However, when you query the table, MySQL knows to return the string instead of the ID. You can also search by the string or the ID. So `WHERE type = 0` and `WHERE type = 'category'` will return the same thing

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's a great solution!

Answer (score 0):

According to your requirements, you can build a [M-M Polymorphic Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations) between `categories`, `contents` & `menus`.

Your table structure should be as:

```
categories
    id - integer
    name - string
    ...

contents
    id - integer
    name - string
    ...

menus
    id - integer
    body - text
    owner_id - integer
    owner_type - string
    ...
```

and your models should look like this:

```
class Menu extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the owning owner models.
     */
    public function owner() // <--------- Get the owner model object
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}

class Category extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the post's owner.
     */
    public function menus() // <--------- Get all the associated Menu Model objects
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Menu', 'owner');
    }
}

class Content extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the video's owner.
     */
    public function menus() // <--------- Get all the associated Menu Model objects
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Menu', 'owner');
    }
}
```

In case of `url` you can let the `owner_id` & `owner_type` fields empty or you can define an extra column `type` to define the type of menu.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks! so I want to store the actual url string like `http://stackoverflow.com` in a column, so I must have a `link` column  for that?

Comment: Yeah, you can have that column too in your menus table!